# Increase PHP variable

Tags: php

I have code that is not working like I want it to and I'm not sure why.

```
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next">
```

then the php...

```
$LimitStart = 0 ;
$LimitNext = 0 ;
```

then other stuff, then....

```
if (isset($_POST['next'])) {
    If ($LimitNext == 0) {
    $LimitNext = $LimitStart + 10 ;
    echo "<br>" ;
    echo $LimitNext ;
    echo "<br>" ;
    } Else {       
    $LimitNext = $LimitNext + 10    ;
    }
```

My goal with this is that when someone hits the "next" button, the first time, since LimitNext will equal 0, $LimitNext will be set to whatever $LimitStart is + 10.  Every time AFTER that that the "next" button is hit, it will increase $LimitNext by 10.  This second part is not working.  $Limitset, which is initially set to 0, obtains the value of 10 after I click the next button, but then it stays there forever and never increases.  Is my syntax wrong?  ($LimitNext = $Limitnext + 10 ;)

Comment: you know php variables are not persistant

Comment: remember the variables by posting/sending back, that's how it should be done.

Comment: No - I don't know what variable persistence means.  How I go about "sending them back?"

Comment: This is surely a case where JavaScript will provide your users with a much better experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (setting limit value in input). Next limit will be set to the `$_POST['limit']` value + 10 (if post is set), or 10 by default. Notice I changed the name of the input.

```
<?php 
   $postedLimit = (isset($_POST['limit']) ? (int) $_POST['limit'] : 0);
   $nextLimit = $postedLimit + 10;
?>

<input type="submit" name="limit" value="<?php echo $nextLimit; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely functions correctly - but the name of my button is no longer "next".  If I don't have any title on this button, no one is going to know what it's for.  The purpose of it is to get the next 10 SQL outputs in a range, as I'll be using that $nextLimit inside of an SQL query.  Is there a way for me to keep the functionality without making the submit button's value <?php echo $nextLimit; ?> ?  If I take that part out and just use "next", the button doesn't work anymore.

Comment: 1. Add apropriate input of type `hidden` and fill it with desired $limit, or

2. try adding some JS if you really need to (but I think you try to take a shortcut rather than doing it properly):
`<input type="submit" name="limit" value="limit" onclick="this.value=<?php echo $nextLimit; ?>"/>`. It will change the value of it on clicking submit, which will post it to the server.

Comment: This is actually a really cool idea.  Thanks!  it works perfectly.  I really appreciate your help on this.